# ItemAttachment as EmailMessage

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange

I am using journaling in Exchange 2010. I use EWS to get emails from journaling mailbox, but original emails are there as attachments. How can i get them as EmailMessge?
Code i am using:

```
ItemAttachment attach = item.Attachments[0] as ItemAttachment;
attach.Load(new PropertySet(
    ItemSchema.Body,
    EmailMessageSchema.ToRecipients,
    EmailMessageSchema.CcRecipients,
    EmailMessageSchema.BccRecipients,
    EmailMessageSchema.From,
    EmailMessageSchema.Subject,
    EmailMessageSchema.DateTimeReceived,
    EmailMessageSchema.DateTimeCreated,
    EmailMessageSchema.DateTimeSent) { RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text });
```

But there i get ItemAttachment and i cannot convert it to EmailMessage. I need to convert, because i need to formard that message.

Answer (score 0):

About a year late, but maybe of help to someone:
I'm using the EWS Java API but it should work the same in Managed API 2.0.

After the attach.Load() statement i do:

```
Item item = attach.getItem();
EmailMessage message = (EmailMessage) item;
```

Now you have a message object with all its members.